# indent output into groupings by header

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to read in a file and write out the results to a file such as a report.  But I want to group like items under a subheading.

For instance, I have 'testconfig' file with the following:

```
group,monitor
group1,"Some item in group1 - with a hypen"
group2,"Some item in group2 - with a hypen"
group2,"Another item in group2, but with a comma"
group2,"Plain old item in group2"
group3,"The first item in group3 - with hypen"
group3,"Another item in group3, including comma"
```

And my code is:

```
import csv

f1 = csv.DictReader(open('testconfig'))
for row in f1:
if row['group'] == 'group1':
    print("Group1: " + '\n' + "   " + row['monitor'])
if row['group'] == 'group2':
    print("Group2: " + '\n' + "   " + row['monitor'])
if row['group'] == 'group3':
    print("Group3: " + '\n' + "   " + row['monitor'])
```

My current output is:

```
Group1:
   Some item in group1 - with a hypen
Group2:
   Some item in group2 - with a hypen
Group2:
   Another item in group2, but with a comma
Group2:
   Plain old item in group2
Group3:
   The first item in group3 - with hypen
Group3:
   Another item in group3, including comma
```

This is what I want:

```
Group1:
   Some item in group1 - with a hypen
Group2:
   Some item in group2 - with a hypen
   Another item in group2, but with a comma
   Plain old item in group2
Group3:
   The first item in group3 - with hypen
   Another item in group3, including comma
```

I understand why I am getting my current results, but havent been able to figure out how to get my desired results.  Im using Python 2.7, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easiest way is to keep track of last printed group

```
f1 = csv.DictReader(open('testconfig'))
last_group = ''
for row in f1:
    if row['group'] != last_group:
        print row['group'] + ':'
        last_group = row['group']
    print "   " + row['monitor']
```

Comment: That worked!  You're missing an open paren at the last print.  Took a couple readings to understand why it works, Im just learning Python, but I understand it now.  Thanks!

Comment: glad to hear it - i fixed the formatting problem - no open required or close - lol

Answer (score 0):

This is what [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) excels at:

```
import csv
import itertools

with open('data.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    reader.next() # skip the first line, which is a header

    for group, text in itertools.groupby(reader, key=lambda x: x[0]):
        print group.capitalize() + ":"
        for line in text:
            print "\t" + line[1]
```

The output:

```
Group1:
    Some item in group1 - with a hypen
Group2:
    Some item in group2 - with a hypen
    Another item in group2, but with a comma
    Plain old item in group2
Group3:
    The first item in group3 - with hypen
    Another item in group3, including comma
```